# My gitignor file did not stop push to GitHub files

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, gitignore, git-push, undo

I learn git and Github and now I added this rule

```
# misc
.env.production
.env.development
.env
```

But when I pushad to GitHub this gitignore file and both `.env.development` and prod. was pushed also very annoying I have to delete Firebase app I think.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If a file is already tracked in a git repository, `.gitignore` has no effect.

Comment: aha but if I want to track the file in my local git but not at Github, how would that be done. This files have Firebase kyes

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by tracking locally but not on github, if it's the same repository, then that's not really how you should be using github. If you want to hide the keys but still have the project on github, private your repo or don't upload the keys and instead only fill them in as you're deploying. You don't have to delete the app, you should be able to regenerate all of the keys and sometimes those keys are exposed to users if it's used directly through your front-end.

Comment: I now read that Firebase for web [Apikeys](https://dotnetthoughts.net/assets/images/2020/05/firebase_sdk_config.png) config keys are public and there is no way to hide them? Is this true. I can restrict the apikey to my website url that's good

Comment: Seems correct as I googled the same thing a few months ago and found my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/11575008)

Comment: ok good to know so the answer to my question is maybe your comment please post and answer and I accept. I dont need to hide the config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is already tracked in a git repository, `.gitignore` has no effect.
With that said, there is no need to hide Firebase Api keys. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/11575008)